# Microsoft graph API --> To see if the message is a reply

Tags: microsoft-graph-mail

I am using the graph API to retrieve the mail from mail folders. For example I got a mail, I will change or edit the subject line and store the conversation id for future use. if I got the reply mail for the same email chain I got different conversation id. How to handle this, I need to find out the reply mail.

```
"subject": "Test",
"conversationId": "AAQkADU1YWM2MjMyLTVkOGQtNDdiMy05YWM4LTE4NTNlYzg1ZWRiNwAQADofdbq8_JtJkY8M5wnunlU=",
```

reply msg:

```
"subject": "Re: Test1",
"conversationId": "AAQkADU1YWM2MjMyLTVkOGQtNDdiMy05YWM4LTE4NTNlYzg1ZWRiNwAQAHu3pWtxNmBFjdfyjYaVGKc=",
```

I need to find this ts reply message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you use the In-Reply-To header https://wesmorgan.blogspot.com/2012/07/understanding-email-headers-part-ii.html in that way you can relate multiple replies (to the same replied to message) in a Message chain etc. You can either get the In-Reply-To header by requesting the InternetHeaders https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/internetmessageheader?view=graph-rest-1.0 (this will return all the headers) or you can request the extended property to just get that one property eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('user@domain.com')/MailFolders('Inbox')/messages/?$select=ReceivedDateTime,Sender,Subject,IsRead,inferenceClassification,InternetMessageId,parentFolderId,hasAttachments,webLink&$Top=10&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=(Id%20eq%20'String%200x1042'))
```

Comment: Great, Thank you. it's solve my problem !... Now i can able to find the reply messages.....

Comment: Sometimes the graph api, returns the InternetMessage Headers  references with single value(immediate parent), even though it contains more parent ID's. for example :                                                                                                               1st mail :  "Subject": "reply mail"                                                                         reply to 1st mail contains, "Subject": "Re: reply mail 1" -->this is ok.                                        reply to 2nd mail contains  single value(2nd mail message id) but first one message id is not included.

Comment: The graph is just showing whats in the Header, the contents of the header is down to the replying client (which there are many) eg it should just be appending to the current header but could be a bug or different implementation by that particular client